# nginx-passenger-rails app won't display

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, passenger

I am recovering from a server failure (rackspace Cloud Server Ubuntu 10.04) and I see this message in the browser:

"The page isn't redirecting properly
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

The browser console log shows a bunch of entries like this:
"
[16:08:44.886] GET https://staging.mydomain.net/ [HTTP/1.1 302 Found 563ms]
[16:08:45.455] GET http://staging.mydomain.net/ [HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently 94ms]
[16:08:45.557] GET https://staging.mydomain.net/ [HTTP/1.1 302 Found 47ms]
[16:08:45.609] GET http://staging.mydomain.net/ [HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently 47ms]
[16:08:45.658] GET https://staging.mydomain.net/ [HTTP/1.1 302 Found 47ms]
[16:08:45.711] GET http://staging.mydomain.net/ [HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently 47ms]
"

In the nginx log, I do not see any problems.
The rails log does show some info.  See comment below.

My question:  how can I gather more information to debug this.

Comment: What does the nginx log say?  Is there an access log?

Comment: Thanks for the response.

nginx error.log

2012/07/24 21:18:08 [warn] 2321#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:34
2012/07/24 21:18:08 [warn] 2321#0: conflicting server name "mydomain.net" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2012/07/24 21:18:08 [warn] 2321#0: conflicting server name "mydomain.net" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored

Comment: rails staging log

lots of entries like this.  Smoking gun here?

Started GET "/" for 71.237.68.50 at 2012-07-24 21:32:34 +0000
2012-07-24 21:32:34.582 INFO   Processing by WelcomeController#welcome
as HTML
2012-07-24 21:32:34.583 WARN DEPRECATION WARNING: Using #request_uri is deprecated. Use fullpath instead. (called from call at /u/apps/mydomain-staging/releases/20120724195008/vendor/bundle/r\
uby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/exception_notification-192a49a02d63/lib/exception_notifier.rb:19)
2012-07-24 21:32:34.583 INFO Redirected to http://staging.mydomain.net/
... INFO Completed 302 Found in 1ms

Comment: I don't think there's an access log.

Comment: Please post a gist of your nginx configuration. Possibly related question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715361/nginx-subdomain-failure-with-rails-app-and-passenger

Comment: I'm thinking that this is a problem within Rails.  I see the "Redirected to staging.mydomain.net" and that ends up in a loop that the browser detects and aborts.

Comment: user www-data;
worker_processes  4;
daemon off;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  2048;
}

more...

Comment: The nginx configuration spans several files and would take multiple comments. Do you need it?

Comment: Yeah, just to be sure we don't miss anything. Use https://gist.github.com/ to post it.

Comment: I've posted the config files at https://github.com/deeptext/nginx-passenger-rails-debug.  Matt, let me know when you've seen them.  Thanks for the help.  All the way from Switzerland?  Oz

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
In my rails apps/controllers/application_controller I had a line: "include SslRequirement"

This was causing a potentially-infinite redirection loop.
For some reason the ssl authentication was failing, redirecting to the home page and then ssl authentication was attempted again.

This is closely related to the line in the nginx config file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomain.net;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rewrite ^/(.*) https://mydomain.net/$1 permanent; 
}
```

Thanks especially to Matt for his help.  He steered me towards the right path.